# Getting Unauthorized 401 from Microsoft Graph API (OneDrive)

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-files

I've been trying to reach Microsoft Graph API, to get list of items on my OneDrive, but suddenly I got error with code 80049217.

I tried use different permissions types (**Files.something**), but nothing work.
I seach up on the internet but I didn't find any solution, that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

To get the List children or items of a driveItem with the following query:

```
GET /me/drive/root/children
```

The permissions required for this query:
[image]

For more information:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-list-children?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried it, it doesn't helped me. None of the permissions worked for me. I still got error 80049217.